# jQuery and React.js aren't playing nice

Tags: jquery, reactjs, pug, react-dom

The error:

```
_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

The line the is causing the is `$('#container')`in main.jsx. When I substitute that for `document.getElementById('container')` all is well. What am I doing wrong? Is jQuery not meant to work with React?

index.jade

```
doctype html
html
    head
        script(src="lib/babel/browser.min.js")
        script(src="lib/react/react.min.js")
        script(src="lib/react/react-dom.min.js")
        script(src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")
    body
        #container

        script(src="public/js/main.jsx", type="text/babel")
```

main.jsx

```
$(function(){
    var Doug = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return (<h1>Hello world</h1>);
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Doug></Doug>,
        $('#container')
    );  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#container')` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element, try `$('#container')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

if you run `console.log($('#container'));` and then check the answer you will see that it doesn't return a DOM object the same way that running `document.getElementById('container');` does.

Logging them both, the jquery one actually returns a jquery object in the jquery fn. namespace (ie `n.fn.init[1]`) that has an array with a reference to that DOM Element. React and jquery should be able to run alongside of each other. I haven't tested it, but you could possibly try something along the lines of:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Doug></Doug>, $('#container').outerHTML());
```

but by that point it just makes more sense to use the native js method to target the render site.